# Iterating multiple rounds when i don t know how many rounds there are going to be

Tags: python

I have researched the different posts and it seems that it is really not recommended to define variable dynamically in python.

i am faced with an issue, I want to analyse multiple rounds (the number of rounds can varry)
I found a way to do it but I find it a little brutal (it involves copy pasting 50 times the same code):

```
def ProcessRound(Input1,Input2,Input3,Source1):
    #the function process the Source and assign the result to Inputs with the right name
    return Input1,Input2,Input3

StopProcess = 0

Source1 = "Text I want to analyse that may exist or not if doesnt exist it is False"

if Source1 != False:
    Input1Rnd1 = []
    Input2Rnd1 = []
    ProcessRound(Input1Rnd1,Input2Rnd1,Source1)
else:
    StopProcess = 1
    #if this step not valid there are no more steps so want to avoid continuing
    
if StopProcess !=1:
    Source2 = "Text2"
    if Source2 != False:
        Input1Rnd2 = []
        Input2Rnd2 = []
        ProcessRound(Input1Rnd2,Input2Rnd2,Source2)
    else:
        StopProcess = 1

#there can be many rounds up to 50 but trying to keep question clear
```

so if I copy and adapt those pargraphs 50 times it works (tested it on the first 5 rounds) but it sounds a bit brute force to me?
Ideally I would much prefer to do something like:

```
def ProcessRound(i,Sourcei):
    #the function process the Source
    return Input1rndi,Input2rndi,Input3rndi
#here the main difference is the the return variable would be named based on the round number:i

StopProcess = 0
i= 0

while StopProcess != 1:
    Sourcei = "Text I want to analyse where i in the name would change"
    if Sourcei != False:
       LastRoundReached = i
       StopProcess = 1
    else:
       ProcessRound(i,Sourcei)
```

If i do this I would get all the variable I need to use (input1rnd1, input2rnd1, input1rnd2...) but don t have to copy paste my code 50 times

it is one of my first question on this site and I am trying to follow proper guidelines but don't hesitate to comment if you think this was not appropriate

Comment: Whenever you find yourself naming variables with a consistent number pattern (Input1, Input2, Input3, etc), you should instead look at using a list, and then you can iterate through the list instead.

Comment: You should use some collection like a list or array or something.

Comment: I  now realise I unfortunately did not word my question correctly. In this case Input1 and input2 are just names i picked to simplify (and they are each different dictionaries - it is a typo in my post that they appear as list) but i did not think doing list of list

Comment: With list you can "assign variables dynamically". Also a small hint, work with True and False instead of 0 and 1. Try to write down the logic of the code with variables then find a way to implement that algorithm and call it repeatedly. There is probably never a need to repeat code. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still a little unclear exactly what you want to do here.  It seems that the main issue you have is in writing a data-driven solution where the processing code can be written once, and then any number of "rounds" can be processed by defining a data structure containing the input for each round.

I gather that in your example, the input for each round is a single string.  That input is processed, and three resulting values are produced by the process.

Here is an example code that illustrates a clean way of addressing the problem defined above:

```
sources = [
    "Text I want to analyse that may exist or not if doesnt exist it is False",
    "Text I want to analyse where i in the name would change",
    "Text2"
]

results = []

def ProcessRound(i, source):
    # the function processes the provided source, resulting in three output values
    result1 = f"<result data for round {i}>"
    result2 = f"<more result data for round {i}>"
    result3 = f"<even more result data for round {i}>"
    return result1, result2, result3

# Process each source in turn...
# "enumerate" gives us an index value for each iteration over our list so
# that we don't have to manage an index variable ourself.
for i, source in enumerate(sources):

    # Process the next source value and store the results in our 'results' list
    results.append((source, ProcessRound(i, source)))

# ... later on, process the results.  If you wanted to do this processing
# at another time, you could store the results in a database instead of an
# in-memory list.  That is left as an exercise for the OP :)
for i, result in enumerate(results):

    # Break out the stored result
    source, (result1, result2, result3) = result

    # Here you would process the results of the round however you want.  As an example,
    # here we just print all of the information we have about the round, including the result
    print(f"Result of round {i}:")
    print("   Input:", source)
    print("   Output:", result1, result2, result3)
```

Result:

```
Result of round 0:
   Input: Text I want to analyse that may exist or not if doesnt exist it is False
   Output: <result data for round 0> <more result data for round 0> <even more result data for round 0>
Result of round 1:
   Input: Text I want to analyse where i in the name would change
   Output: <result data for round 1> <more result data for round 1> <even more result data for round 1>
Result of round 2:
   Input: Text2
   Output: <result data for round 2> <more result data for round 2> <even more result data for round 2>
```

UPDATE: I updated my answer per the OPs desire to store the processing results and then utilize the results later on.  Note that I store the original `source` in each result record so that the exact same processing code as in my original answer can be run later on with no change.  The result is therefore identical.

Comment: thank you for your answer doesn t completely solve my problem but put me in the right direction. I need to be able to reuse result1, result2, result3 of all rounds after but I guess if instead i put them in a disctionary there I will kind of solve my problem?

Comment: @NicolasRenaud - I get yah. Yeah, it would be easy to add storage of the results.  I can even add a solution for that if you want.

Comment: @NicolasRenaud - I expanded my answer to demonstrate storing off the results of the processing and then utilizing them later on.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to follow what you are intending (for example, you indicate you would like to return something from the function but you don't use it?) but it should follow three design components:

3. Processing Logic
   This is the logic you are using against each round of input. I assume this is what your function is for.

```py
    Input1, Input2, Input3 = ProcessRecord(Source)
```

2. Looping Logic
   This is where you determine what condition your loop stops with. This is the most confusing part where `if Source != False:` with contents assigned to `Source` means it is always true?

Either you are looking for a particular terminating `Source`:

```py
    if Source == 'terminating':
      break # end loop
    # Processing Logic
```

or you want to stop when there simply is no more input:

```py
for Source in [Source1, Source2, Source3, ...]:
  # Processing Logic
```

alternatively you can also record how many:

```py
for LastRoundReached, Source in enumerate([Source1, Source2, Source3, ...]):
  # Processing Logic
# LastRoundReached remains as a variable with the value of the last iteration
```

1. Data
   The data you are feeding into your loop. Aka, where is your `Source` coming from? This is also confusing.

If your `Source` is a line in a file:

```py
with open('filename', mode='rt') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

for Source in lines:
  # Processing Logic
```

If your `Source` is user input:

```py
Source = input('prompt (Enter to exit)>')
while Source:
  # Processing Logic
  Source = input('prompt (Enter to exit)>')
```

If your `Source` is hard-coded:

```py
AllSource = [
  `Source1`,
  `Source2`,
  `Source3`,
  ...
]

for Source in AllSource:
  # Processing Logic
```

I assume, based on your posted code, that you are entirely dealing with strings, but these ways could work otherwise.

To note: I might assume that you want the return of the `ProcessRecord` to be accumulated so you would want something like:

```py
Input1Accumulated = []
Input2Accumulated = []
Input3Accumulated = []

for Source in ...:
  Input1, Input2, Input3 = ProcessRecord(Source)
  Input1Accumulated.append(Input1)
  Input2Accumulated.append(Input2)
  Input3Accumulated.append(Input3)
```

Comment: sorry if it was unclear, tried to dumb down a code that is quite complex(for me) to something easier to read where all the specific operations I do to fin the data are hidden. I think my biggest flow is i did not think how I could just assign the output of my function   Input1, Input2, Input3 = ProcessRecord(Source)  and then put it in dictionary i think

Comment: That is ok, just means I made assumptions and gave you multiple options to apply back to the real code.

Answer (score -2):

Not much of an improvment, but you can use `exec` with f-strings to avoid copy-pasting the code 50 times:

```py
for i in range(1, 51):
    exec(f"if StopProcess !=1:\n"
         f"    Source{i} = 'Text{i}'\n"
         f"    if Source{i} != False:\n"
         f"        Input1Rnd{i} = []\n"
         f"        Input2Rnd{i} = []\n"
         f"        ProcessRound(Input1Rnd{i},Input2Rnd{i},Source{i})\n"
         f"    else:\n"
         f"        StopProcess = 1")
```

Comment: Using `exec` is not the way to go here.  Instead, you want to write the code in question so that it is directly parameterized.  If this sort of solution made good sense, Python, and other modern languages, would have the notion of a "macro". The fact that the idea of "macros" hasn't been added to a language since C/C++ was invented shows that this sort of approach was long ago considered to not be a good idea.

Comment: @Steve I know, that's why I said *"Not much of an improvment, but you can use `exec` with f-strings to avoid copy-pasting the code 50 times:"*. This is just to solve the copy-paste issue, it seems to be very tedious to copy-paste the code 50 times each time changing the code a little bit. Maybe this should've been just a comment, but it solves the problem (I'll admit, not efficiently) and you can't include code in comments.

Comment: I getcha.  Your solution isn't at all inefficient.  If the job were never going to change...if that's all that was ever going to be needed from the code, then maybe it saves a little recoding time.  What it is, however, is hard to maintain as a project grows.  The better alternative of using the programming language as a full-featured language that allows elegant solutions to just this sort of problem instead of this one is so worth doing that I consider this to be pushing the beginning programmer in the wrong direction.